Register different users with different properties in laravel 10?
I am new to laravel and I am trying to understand how I can register 2 types of users: Artist and Client. I deleted the users migration And I have two tables, one for artists and one for clients. However, when I try to register either one I get the following error message:
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation \"users\" does not exist\nLINE 1: select count(*) as aggregate from \"users\" where \"username\" =...\n                                          ^ (Connection: pgsql, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from \"users\" where \"username\" = user)
and the code for registering an Artist is the same as the one for Client and goes as follows:
   public function registerArtist(Request $request): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
    {
        $validated = $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        $artist = $this->createArtist($validated);
        Auth::guard('artist')->login($artist);
        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($artist);
        return response()->json(['jwt' => $token], 201);
    }

JWTAuth is imported from use PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\JWTAuth;
I am having a hard time understanding why it is causing an issue. I have ran all migrations, cleared cache, imlemented JWT authentication as well as I know how to, but still cannot fix the issue. Please help if you can : )

What would be an example of the differing properties be between those two? (versus the common properties) ... Personally, I would never go down the road of adding yet-another-table for every type of user that might be added in the future.
